# asp:gridview change cursor in header when mouseover

Tags: gridview

In the asp:GridView control, is there a way to not use a pointer cursor when a user hovers overs the column header?

In other words - In the asp:GridView control, when a user mouses over the header in the grid, it currently changes to a pointer cursor - i do not want this, as the grid is not sortable, i do not want the user to assume the header has any type of action, as is indicated by the pointer going from a normal (arrow) cursor into a pointer (finger) cursor.

thank you

take care
tony

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvEnrollments" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="grid"
        ShowHeader="true" HeaderStyle-CssClass="VSAGridHeader" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alternating" runat="server" Width="100%">
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            There are no unassigned Enrollments.
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the GridView control is just rendering an HTML table there must be some CSS (either inline or an included file) that is changing the cursor. You could add something like the following to a css file (or inline in the aspx file) to override

```
th {
   cursor: default
}
```

Unfortunately you do not provide any sample code (either from the aspx or from the rendered html) to provide a more specific answer.